# Google AppEngine button has disappeared from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I have been using Eclipse to develop for AppEngine, and have always had a handy blue button in the toolbar to use for deployments. Now it's gone, and I don't know how to deploy any more!

I've tried:

- Looking for likely options in the "Customize Perspective" dialog... but I'm not sure what to look for
- Updating the Google Plugin for Eclipse... but apparently it's already up to date

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what changed in order to cause this. Please help me get my button back!

Comment: So... not exactly a great solution, but removing Eclipse entirely and then reinstalling did work.

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse top menu choose WINDOW --> SHOW VIEW and it should be one of the options.  If not, choose OTHER and navigate the dialog till you find it under Google.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However, there's no entry for anything mentioning Google in the Show View menu or the Show View window.

Comment: Try customize perspective --> Tool Bar Visibility --> check Google